# Start scraping only after and before certain element

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Cars</li>
    <li>Bikes</li>
    <li>Planes</li>
</ul>

<h4>Brands</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Mercedes</li>
</ul>

<h4>FAQ</h4>
<ul>
    <li>FAQ1</li>
    <li>FAQ2</li>
    <li>FAQ3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to extract only the brands using Scrapy. There are no distinguishing features between the category vs. brands section except that the H4 begins the new section. Also, there are many categories and brands so it's hard to hardcode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) or [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis.

For instance, in order to get the brands you can get to the desired `h4` element by text and then get to the next `ul` sibling via `following-sibling`:

```
//h4[. = 'Brands']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()
```

Demo from the Scrapy shell:

```
$ scrapy shell ./index.html
>>> response.xpath("//h4[. = 'Brands']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()").extract()
['Audi', 'BMW', 'Mercedes']
```